Getting 504 (Gateway Timeout) while hitting /api/auth/session endpoint in vercel deployed app
I am stuck into this issue while using useSession function while trying to hit /login endpoint in Next.js based webapp.
[GET] /api/auth/session?nxtPnextauth=session status=504
I keep getting this response on the screen: "this Serverless Function has timed out"
Also, the same app works like butter at localhost.
My app is currently deployed at vercel. And what I got to know from other blogs that vercel (hobby-plan) gives 10s of time for serverless functions execution, and I can see that this limit is getting exhausted since /api/auth/session isn't able to return response within this 10s duration.
Can anyone let me know any workaround to resolve this issue? I will be really glad.
Thanks in advance

The saviour for those who doesn't want to pay is Microsoft Edge. The documentation mentions: You can't configure a maximum duration for functions using the Edge runtime. They can run indefinitely provided they send an initial response within 25 seconds.
So, simply install Edge and you are good to go. Atleast, I am continuing my app's development now.
